# Doctrine2 association mapping with conditions

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

is it possible to have association mapping with conditions in Doctrine 2.4? I have entities Article and Comment. Comments needs to be approved by admin. Approval status of comment is stored in boolean field "approved.

Now I have @OneToMany association mapping to comments in entity Article. It maps all the comments. But I would like to map only approved comments.

Something like

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", where="approved=true", mappedBy="article")
```

would be very helpful. Unfortunately AFAIK there is no such thing as where condition in mapping, so I tried to solve my problem with inheritance - I created two subclasses of class Comment. Now I have ApprovedComment and NotApprovedComment and SINGLE_TABLE inheritance mapping.

```
 @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="approved", type="integer")
 @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({1 = "ApprovedComment", 0 = "NotApprovedComment"})
```

Problem is, since "approved" column is discriminator, I cannot use it as field in entity Comment anymore.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use the Criteria API to filter [the collection](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections):

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

class Article
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="article")
     */
    protected $comments;

    public function getComments($showPending = false)
    {
        $criteria = Criteria::create();
        if ($showPending !== true) {
            $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('approved', true));
        }
        return $this->comments->matching($criteria);
    }

}
```

This is especially nice, because Doctrine is smart enough to only go to the database if the collection hasn't already been loaded.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it can filter on SQL level. This is exactly what I need! :)

Comment: Doesn't work with ManyToMany. I get this error: Undefined index: relationToSourceKeyColumns.

Comment: Haven't tried but by the looks of it, it would fit the work I need very nicely!

Comment: It seems that this way of filtering results in a new query to DB on every call to `getComments`

Comment: How is this nice? Do you really have to create a custom method instead of just defining the field relationship ? -_-