# Symfony where clause on the entity level

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got two entities that are linked together by a one-to-many relationship and I'm using soft deletes on both entities. Because I'm using soft deletes however, reading data is a little bit more tricky because I need to check if the deleted flag is set to false before reading it out.

The basic setup of the entities are:

```
class Division extends MasterData {
    ...

    /**
     * @var Asset
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Asset", mappedBy="division")
     */
   private $assets;


   public function __construct() {
       $this->assets = new ArrayCollection();
   }

   public function getAssets() {
       return $this->assets;
   }

   public function addAssets(Asset $asset) {
       $this->assets[] = $asset;
       return $this;
   }

   ...
}
```

```
class Asset extends MasterData {
    ...

    /**
     * @var Division
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Division", inversedBy="assets")
     */
    private $division;

    ...
}
```

```
class MasterData {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted", type="boolean", options={"default":0})
     */
    protected $deleted;

   public function __construct() {
       $this->deleted = 0;
   }

   ...
}
```

*These are only snippets of the entities, not the entire thing.*

When I am in the controller for a `Division`, I'd like to pull a list of all the `Assets` that are related to that division and are not marked as deleted. I can see a couple ways of doing this.

An easy solution would be to create a custom repository to handle the pull of data. This however would provide a limitation when I would like to further filter data (using `findBy()` for example).

A second solution would be to alter the `getAssets()` function in the `Division` entity to only return assets that are not deleted. This however means that I'm pulling all of the data from the database, then filtering it out post which is very inefficient.

Ideally, I'm looking for a way to alter the definition in the entity itself to add a where clause for the asset itself so that way the filtering is happening in the entity removing the needs for custom repositories and a more efficient option. Similar as to how I can define `@ORM\OrderBy()` in the annotations, is there a way to similar to this that lets me filter out deleted assets pre-execution and without a custom repository?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine does not support conditional associations in mapping. To achive this behavior you can use [Criteria API in the entity methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23458717/1220930). And yes, in this case all data will be fetched from DB before applying condition.

But Doctrine (>=2.2) supports [Filters](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html). This feature allows to add some SQL to the conditional clauses of all queries. Soft-deletes can be implemented through this feature.

The [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) library already has this functionality ([**SoftDeletable**](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md), based on Filters API).

Also, many don't recommend to use soft-deletes ([1](https://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/73), [2](http://jameshalsall.co.uk/posts/why-soft-deletes-are-evil-and-what-to-do-instead)).

Comment: I figured out how to use a criteria for a collection within the division entity which works great! However for the entire division entity, the only way I could apply the criteria was in the controller. `$em->getRepository->('AppBundle:Division')->matching($criteria);` Is there then a way to make it use the criteria by default, that way I can retain the use of the functions `findBy()` for example?

Comment: You can create a custom repository class and override the findBy method. But i yet think that Filters API is a more suitable for your case.