# How to setup Doctrine entity associations when table uses a generic foreign key pattern?

Tags: doctrine-orm, generic-foreign-key

We inherited a 3rd party database schema where several tables use a database
design pattern in which tables do not define foreign keys *directly*, but in
a way where some tables do so by a combination of two columns:

- a column specifying name of table:

  - either directly (ENUM `type`)
  - or by means of another table (`type_id` referencing table `types`, which then contains table name in a varchar column)
- a column specifying PK value from said table (e.g. `type_value`)

This results in a scenario where one row references one table while another
row may reference a completely different table.

We can use query builder and define JOIN and WHERE clauses manually for each
scenario, but it'd be more practical to have one property for each foreign
table and use WHERE clause to filter target table results only, e.g.:

```
class Foo {
    private $id;       // PK for Foo
    private $type;     // string (enum), e.g. 'bar' or 'baz'
    private $type_id;  // contains PK of Bar or Baz, respectivelly
    private $bar;      // references entity Bar
    private $baz;      // references entity Baz
}
```

The closest thing to what we need which I managed to find is to use Criteria API
to update the WHERE clause dynamically in getter methods (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23458717/282325)).

However I'm completely lost in terms of how to setup Doctrine annotations in
this case. Does Doctrine support a DB schema such as this one, or do we have to
fall back to building each query manually via query builder or DQL?

Comment: Note that I'm note sure what's the official name for the DB design pattern where you have table name in one column and an ID in another one. I'd be grateful if anyone can provide the name - I'd then edit/tag the question accordingly.

Comment: Django calls this feature `GenericForeignKey`, and I had a feeling I'd find a lot of articles on why it's a DB design anti-pattern. Unfortunately there's not much we can do to alter the schema on our end.